# Form file field validation with php

Tags: php

I have a file field in a form where I want people to upload their CV.  The problem is getting it to validate correctly and it seems that even if i add a file it still says the file hasn't been uploaded.

Here is my form html for the file field.

```
 <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Upload Your CV"  /><?php echo $form->error("file"); ?>
```

And below is the PHP

```
  function procRegister(){
  global $session, $form;
  /* Convert username to all lowercase (by option) */
  if(ALL_LOWERCASE){
     $_POST['user'] = strtolower($_POST['user']);
  }

  /* Registration attempt */
  $retval = $session->register($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['telephone'], $_POST['county'], $_POST['job_title'], $_POST['workinindustry'], $_POST['industry_years'], $_POST['salary_range'], $_POST['public'], $_POST['file'], $_POST['postcode'], $_POST['sia_question'], 
  $_POST['sia_license_num'], $_POST['ip1'], $_POST['ip2']);

  /* Registration Successful */
  if($retval == 0){
     $_SESSION['reguname'] = $_POST['user'];
     $_SESSION['regsuccess'] = true;
     $newuser =$_POST['user'];
      $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET flinks='$new_file_name' WHERE username='$newuser'") or die(mysql_error()); 
     header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
  }
  /* Error found with form */
  else if($retval == 1){
     $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
     $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
     header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
  }
  /* Registration attempt failed */
  else if($retval == 2){
     $_SESSION['reguname'] = $_POST['user'];
     $_SESSION['regsuccess'] = false;
     header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
    }
 }

  function register($subuser, $subpass, $subemail, $subfirstname, $sublastname, $subtelephone, $subcounty, $subjob_title, $subworkinindustry, $subindustry_years, $subsalary_range, $subpublic, $subfile, $subpostcode, $subsia_question, $subsia_license_num, $ip1, $ip2){
  global $database, $form, $mailer;  //The database, form and mailer object

  /* Username error checking */
   /* First Name error checking */
  $field = "file";
   if(strlen($subfile) < 2){
     $form->setError($field, "* CV Not Added");
  }
  else{  

  }
```

SO this is the code to validate the file and it isn't getting beyong this point as it it returning the error CV NOT Added and so it doesn't get to the insert script.

Comment: there isn't enough form code here or how it's supposed to be handled; uploaded? saved to db? other? The **less** we have, the **more time** it takes to give you a solution. Good luck till then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue in your code is that you are using `$_POST` Super Global for getting uploaded file:

```
$_POST['file']
```

When you are using `input=file` in your form than you can only get file values in `$_FILES`. So this should be:

```
$_FILES['file']
```

**Side note:**

One more point make sure your file upload form has attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` otherwise the file upload will not work.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

[PHP Manual File Uploading](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: Thanks, i actually just tried the code with the field as text and it worked and so realised it was to do with the file type.  Thank you I will check it now

Comment: @samw003801 sure test it.